# Query regarding surnames and UK Visa applications

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, paperwork, names

I recently got married , and then applied for a passport. The passport has my husband's name as my surname. But in the rest of my documents I have my father's name as my surname.

Will it be an issue while I apply for uk spouse visa?

Should I fill my husband's name as my surname in the UK visa application?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a problem. The relevant questions from the [Family Settlement Application Form](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/274029/VAF4A.pdf) are:

> 1.2 **Family name** (as shown in your passport)
>
> 1.3 **Other names** (including any other names you are known by and/or any other names that you have been known by)

(Other forms for other visa types all seem similar, if you're filling out a different one then follow the directions on that form.)

In question 1.2, enter your husband's surname. In question 1.3, enter your full name with your father's surname. You will also submit your marriage certificate which should clarify the matter further.